# arrange java output in excel file

Tags: java, excel

I have a java program that prints 1000 integer values each I run it. I want to copy the output to an excel file each time I run the program. I want to output the first run in the first column in excel file and then copy the next runs in the subsequent columns in the same excel file. 
For example:

```
Run: 1
value1
value2
.
.
value1000
Run:2
value1
value2
.
.
value1000
```

I want the first output in the first column of an excel file and the second output in the second column

Here is my code:

```
int rownum=1;
int cellnum=1;
File file; 
HSSFWorkbook workbook;
HSSFSheet sheet;
HSSFRow row;
HSSFCell cell;

HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sample sheet");

public void writeOutput(double meandispersion) {    

    String dispersion = Double.toString(meandispersion);

    HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
    HSSFCell cell = row.createCell(cellnum);    
    cell.setCellValue("dispersion");

    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("newFile.xls");
        workbook.write(out);
        out.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   

}
```

There are a total of 1000 time steps in the main code and in each time step this method is called and the value of meandispersion is passed to it. It prints the 1000 values in 1000 rows in the first column. The problem is that when I run the program second time I want to copy the 1000 values in the second column, for third run 3rd column and so on. Currently it is not appending the values, it overwrites the entire file. Can anyone point out the problem?

Comment: By Excel do you mean specifically a .xlsx file or simply a file that can be opened in Excel?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to write your results in a CSV file. This kind of file is easy to handle from Java, and Excel will open it properly.

You can check out [my CsvUtils repository](https://github.com/joffrey-bion/CsvUtils) if you want some helper classes to read/write/merge such files.

Answer (score 0):

if the Excel is open, you can manipulate it via **Dynamic Data Exchange (DDE) protocol**.

I have used the following library for that purpose: [java DDE library](http://jdde.pretty-tools.com/en/examples/)

Answer (score 0):

You should use an API to write to an excel file like the following:

[Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/index.html)

[jexcelapi](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/)  [Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaExcel/article.html)

Comment: I use the following code. The problem is that each time I run my I increase the column number but the program deletes the previous values rather than appending the new values

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution:

- Use CSV file

  - text file
  - first row establishes headers
  - each subsequent row is an entry with columns separated by commas
- append a new row each cycle

  ```
  surname,firstname
  doe,john
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a utility (backed by Apache POI) that probably you'll need. Using the utility is easy, just create your own Excel template design. It may include some placeholders which you may change from your Java program. When the template design is ready, just create an instance of the class `CreateExcel()` and then `execute()`.

Here's the link for the source code: [Java - CreateExcel](http://pastebin.com/kKfLTwcY)

Samples are included to get you started.

Cheers!